# Do not count already viewed chat replies in the top bar inbox

Tags: feature-request, chat, top-bar, global-inbox

If you use chat you should know that chat replies (using your username in messages in general) can lead to an increasing inbox count for the top bar inbox:

> [image: inbox]

This happens if you are not currently (or just inactive some amount of time) in chat. Visiting chat and clearing all the chat notifications (by clicking possibly a several times on the number in circle or sending a new chat message) doesn’t clear the notification from the top bar inbox.

> [image: chat notifications count]

The current behavior is slightly confusing because I see old (already viewed) items as new (not read) in the top bar inbox.

I suggest to not count (substract them) already cleared chat notifications in the top bar inbox.

Comment: That's incorrect. Once a chat ping became a notification, you can't clear it anymore in chat itself. Whatever you clear, is NOT something that turned into notification. It's either a new ping, which by clearing it you prevented yet more inbox items, or old ping that clearing it has no effect, and that would go away upon reload as well. All in all, this request is moot since it is based on incorrect logic.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard “you can’t clear it anymore” this is exactly what I would like to change in the current FR. I don’t understand what you mean by “incorrect logic”

Comment: I mean " Visiting the chat and clearing the all chat notifications" - what you mean by that? How you "clear all chat notifications"?

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard see post update

Comment: Exactly my point. This number does not appear for chat messages that already turned into notifications. :)